# A game of charades

Tags: cryptic-clues

Here are ten cryptic clues in [the "charade" style](/a/45985/93), meaning that that's the only wordplay involved. That's a big hint for a cryptic clue! — so I'm not giving you letter counts.

- Second-rate wafer material is bitter
- Hurry up! Leave us, heretic
- Top student from a southern port
- Glass engraving is offensive
- Duke's state: sober
- Check flower for return to life
- Cleveland site was erected near jelly, perhaps
- "Facial hair is a necessity" —a Fidel supporter
- Belted girls to obtain a form of protection
- Nixon and Carter backer

(These don't combine into one master puzzle or anything like that. They're just ten separate clues. Oh, and I'll provide letter counts if needed after a time.)

---

**Hint** added later:  The respective letter counts (in order) are

> 6; 7; 10; 9; 9; 13; 9,7; 8; 10; and 6.

**Hint** added even later:

> "Top" is perhaps slightly unfair. Better would be "Max, a student from a southern port".

**Hint** added even later: The respective first letters of the answers (in order) are

> B, R, C, P, L, R, R, M, S, and P.

**Hint** added even later: The respective definition halves of the clues are at (in order) their

> end, end, end, end, start, end, start, start, end, and end.

**Hint** added even later: Only three clues remain unsolved. Hints for them are:

> *Second-rate wafer material is bitter*: The attempted answer had the right sense of "bitter".

> *Top student from a southern port*: The definition half is "from a southern port".

> *Cleveland site was erected near jelly, perhaps*: Not Ohio.

Comment: Would you like to clarify whether "charade-style" means only that the _top-level_ construction is a charade, or whether it means that that's the _only_ wordplay? E.g., "Be impressed by promotion of mixed-up rime (6)", solution ADMIRE, is charade-style in the first sense but not the second because one of the components in the charade is an anagram. (Also, it's a terrible clue, but it's just an example.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick perusal over morning coffee can provide one small contribution:

> Check flower for return to life  -  REINCARNATION [REIN + CARNATION]
>  "Facial hair is a necessity" —a Fidel supporter - MUSTACHE [MUST + A + CHE]

And a couple more over dinner

> Belted girls to obtain a form of protection - SUNGLASSES [SUNG + LASSES]
>  Nixon and Carter backer - PATRON [PAT + RON]. How long did I spend trying combinations of Richard and Jimmy!?

Looks like I'm needing those clues, but another one solved over morning coffee

> Hurry up! Leave us, heretic - RUSHDIE [RUSH + DIE]

Starting to be a little less confident now.....

> Duke's state: sober - LANDGRAVE [LAND + GRAVE]

And now clutching at straws I think, unless more clues are on the horizon......

> Glass engraving is offensive - PHILIPPIC [PHILIP + PIC?]  not sure how pic fits in here
>  Second-rate wafer material is bitter - BRUMAL [B + RUMAL?] not sure how wafer would fit in here

Tidying these up and combining the contributions from the comments below...thanks to JeremyDover, El-Guest and Tom combining for a great community effort.  A really nice puzzle that kept me far too busy not doing what I should have been doing for a week.

Final answers we know are correct

> 1. Second-rate wafer material is bitter - BALTIC [B + AlTiC] (thanks Tom)
>  2. Hurry up! Leave us, heretic - RUSHDIE [RUSH + DIE]
>  3. Top student from a southern port - CAPETONIAN [CAP + ETONIAN]  (thanks El-Guest)
>  4. Glass engraving is offensive - PHILIPPIC [PHILIP + PIC]
>  5. Duke's state: sober - LANDGRAVE [LAND + GRAVE]
>  6. Check flower for return to life  -  REINCARNATION [REIN + CARNATION]
>  7. Cleveland site was erected near jelly, perhaps - ROSEBERRY TOPPING [ROSE + BERRY TOPPING]  (thanks JeremyDover)
>  8. "Facial hair is a necessity" —a Fidel supporter - MUSTACHE [MUST + A + CHE]
>  9. Belted girls to obtain a form of protection - SUNGLASSES [SUNG + LASSES]
>  10. Nixon and Carter backer - PATRON [PAT + RON].

Comment: Yep, those two were my intended solutions.

Comment: And your next two, too, were my intended solutions. Nicely found. Keep it up!

Comment: @msh210 - i haven’t given up - thanks for the clues

Comment: Your fifth solution is also as I intended.

Comment: Your sixth (to "Duke's…") is also as I intended. Nice job.

Comment: Your "Glass engraving…" solution is as I intended. (Google "full-page engraving".) Your "Second-rate…" solution is not, I'm afraid. I'll add a hint imminently.

Comment: So with the clue, #7 is rot13(Ebfroreel Gbccvat = ebfr + oreel tbccvat).

Comment: Also, #3 is rot13(PNCRGBAVNA = PNC + RGBAVNA). @long

Comment: @JeremyDover yep!

Comment: @El-Guest yep !

Comment: 1) rot13(Onygvp) for bitter, rot13(O + NYGVP sbe Nyhzvahz-Gvgnavhz-Pneoba juvpu vf n fhofgengr zngrevny)

Comment: @Tom, yes, indeed!